# Excel interpreting 0% as a large number

Tags: vba, excel

I am encountering a strange error when trying to use `VBA` to implement some formulas. Here is the formula I'm using to place "0.00%" instead of an error message in my cells:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("F6").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-1], ""0.00%"")"
```

Now it places the 0.00% just fine, but even when its cell type is defined as percentage, if I sort largest to smallest by % it places the 0s at the top...

[image: Largest to smallest]
Here you can see where the 0s are placed on top even when doing largest to smallest. And the cell types are set properly to percentage as well:

[image: percentage]
Any idea what's going on here?

I have also tried just placed in `0.00` instead of `0.00%` as well as `0%` and "0", all of those options still showing 0 as being considered a "large number". The only reason that they're not green in the picture above is because I set a conditional formatting rule to stop turning 0s green (when the number is greater than 1).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `""0.00%""` is putting the value in as text.  And as such when Excel Sorts Descending it puts Text first.

You need to just put in 0 and format the cells as percent.  So replace the `""0.00%""` with `0`. No quotes.  The quotes are forcing the number to text.

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("SM Summaries").Range("F6").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-1], 0)"
```

Comment: Ahhhh... No quotes.... I was wondering what the heck was going on... Even after converting it all to text, all back to percentage, the result was the same... Quotes removed and it's all working now, thanks~